# Assigning to ID Nullable from Incompatible Types

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller

I have this warning showing up in XCode that I can't seem to get rid of.

> Assigning to 'id < UINavigationControllerDelegate,  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate > _Nullable '  from incompatibale type 'MyViewController * const _strong'

on this line:

`picker.delegate = self;`

This line of code causes the application to work as expected. **So removing it, it doesn't work. But I don't know how to get rid of the error. Any help?**

Other methods that have delegate assigned are not throwing this warning.

The view controller is a part of a TabBarViewController that is embedded in a NavigationController.

My class inherits the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

```
@interface MyViewController () <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout> {

}
///...
@end
```

And the complete method.

```
- (void) showImagePickerForSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    picker.delegate = self; ///HERE IS THE ISSUE
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    picker.modalTransitionStyle   = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
        picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
    }

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in addition to `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.

```
@interface MyViewController () <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout> {

}
```

Comment: That fixes the issue. Do you happen to have a quick link to some documentation that states that is a requirement? Why did other delegates throw that warning?

Comment: The documentation is found for the `delegate` property of `UIImagePickerController`. It is declared as `@property(nullable,nonatomic,weak) id <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> delegate;`. That means whatever is assigned to the property must conform to both of those protocols.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is one I am just gonna have to commit to memory.

Comment: Why do you need to commit to memory? It's documented and if you make a mistake the compiler tells you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `UINavigationControllerDelegate` along with the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` hides that warning for me.

In the UIKit the delegate for image picker is specified as:

```
@property(nullable,nonatomic,weak) id <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

**From the Documentation:**

The image picker’s delegate object.

**Declaration**

**SWIFT**

```
weak var delegate: protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>?
```

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> delegate
```

**Discussion**

The delegate receives notifications when the user picks an image or movie, or exits the picker interface. The delegate also decides when to dismiss the picker interface, so you must provide a delegate to use a picker. If this property is nil, the picker is dismissed immediately if you try to show it.

Comment: `UINavigationControllerDelegate` does take care of the warning. but `UINavigationBarDelegate` doesn't.

Comment: yes you are right, I miss typed it. It should hide that warning. Please clean your project and build agian to see the change.@Firemarble